# Using py2exe to compile a script with a numpy dependency crashes with this error:

Tags: python, numpy, py2exe, openblas

```
error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 
'libopenblas.UWVN3XTD2LSS7SFIFK6TIQ5GONFDBJKU.gfortran-win32.dll'
```

How do I resolve this issue? I'm running Python 2.7 and I'm on Windows 10 64 bit.

Comment: What script did you use?  How did you compile?  Please add an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48728067/where-can-i-get-obscure-dll-so-py2exe-will-compile/48733540#48733540