# Where can I get obscure DLL so py2exe will compile?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dll, gfortran, py2exe

I am running py2exe to convert a rather large (~20k lines) python file into an executable. It's an older program and is written in python 2.7, 32 bit, so it does not translate well to a minimum working example. On running py2exe I encounter the following error:

```
error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 
'libopenblas.UWVN3XTD2LSS7SFIFK6TIQ5GONFDBJKU.gfortran-win32.dll'
```

Having this dll in the Python27/DLLs folder will solve this issue, but after scouring the depths of google I have been unable to make any progress. My question: where can one download this dll, or a library which would contain this dll?

Comment: It should already be on your system if you can run the original python script. I would try using PyInstaller.

Comment: Unfortunately PyInstaller errors out. I did get Py2exe working, I found the .DLL on my system. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Problem solved. If you're running 32 bit python and numpy, you should be able to find this specific DLL at:

```
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\numpy\.libs
```

Copy and paste this into:

```
C:\Python27\DLLs
```

And run py2exe as normal.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Dr.Toboggan's answer, you can probably just import numpy inside the setup.py file for p2exe, this is what worked for me on a 64-bit system...

Comment: Worked for me in 32 bits as well.